# Can I have an iOS process await a debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

When testing my iOS app, my code will sometimes encounter an unexpected situation (a lite assertion failure) that will show me an alert to let me know the file and line where the problem occurred.

However, by this point, I've already gone past the actual point where the "assertion" failed, so even if I attach LLDB to the process, there's not much to look at.

Is there a way to sort of pause the iOS process until I get a debugger attached, so LLDB will be operating right at the point of the failure, with access to the call stack, variables, etc? I don't want the app to crash, as it would with a simple assert.

Comment: In what sense has the app "already gone past the actual point where the 'assertion' failed"? Is it not still in the `assert()` call (or equivalent)? Can you not just walk up the stack (in the debugger) to see the context of that call? I mean, if you could pause and wait for the debugger, wouldn't that just be in the same context as your alert code?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is easy -- add a busyloop to your program.  In C terms, you might have a file static like

```
static int wait_for_debugger = 1;
```

and then at the point where you have your soft assertion,

```
if (bad_condition)
{
    while (wait_for_debugger)
        sleep (1);
}
```

And when you've hit that condition in your app, the thread will wait at this point forever until you attach with a debugger and do something like

```
(lldb) e wait_for_debugger = 0
```

The complication I see with an iOS app is that if your app stops responding to events, SpringBoard is going to notice and think your app is hung and kill it off.  If your event loop on the main thread was still executing you would be fine, but then having another thread sitting in this busyloop would probably lead to other problems.  When the debugger is attached to an iOS process, SpringBoard knows that it is OK for the app to stop responding to events (you might be stopped at a breakpoint, for instance) but if it is running free, I don't see that working.

The other alternative is to have the debugger attached to the app the whole time until you've reproduced the failure -- but I'm assuming that it only happens occasionally?  so that might be an extra bit of work to launch it from Xcode (or attach to it from Xcode) every time until you repo the failure.  On the other hand, if you can go with the "always running under the debugger" model, you can just use a breakpoint on your soft assertion.

Comment: Right - the issue only happens occasionally so I don’t always have Xcode attached. Reliable wireless debugging has made this a bit easier but I still don’t always have the debugger running.

Comment: You need `wait_for_debugger` to be `volatile` or the compiler can optimize the read of it away.

Comment: Hmm, at `-O0` I'd expect the compiler to keep the symbol around because it's actually used in the function, although I could see a compiler making it a const value because it's never modified and using the const in the loop.  Removing the `static` storage qualifier would probably keep the compiler honest in that case; it's harder for the compiler to know it isn't modified elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an actual answer. I apologize, but the exploration was just too interesting not to share, too long to put in a comment, and I would love to see someone build on this.**

I started by setting the app up to be debugged (PT_TRACE_ME), and then triggering a breakpoint (SIGTRAP). This is just called from an button IBAction in Swift.

```
#include "debug.h"
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef int (*ptrace_ptr_t)(int _request, pid_t _pid, caddr_t _addr, int _data);

void debugme() {
    void* handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    ptrace_ptr_t ptrace_ptr = dlsym(handle, "ptrace");
    ptrace_ptr(0, 0, 0, 0);
    dlclose(handle);
    kill(0, SIGTRAP);
}
```

(I am certain this will ban you from the app store. I would never include this in the production build of a shipping app.)

This comes *so* close to working (sending yourself `SIGTRAP` does work if you're already running under Xcode, but in that case you can just set a breakpoint). It hangs the program, the program is not killed for failing to process its runloop, and it shows up in the "Debug, attach to process" list as a likely target. But, when you try to actually connect Xcode complains that it can't connect to it. In the iOS logs you get:

```
default 16:10:52.889240 -0400   debugserver error: Attach failed: "(os/kern) invalid task".
```

This probably shouldn't be surprising since the app's parent isn't expecting it to be debugged. So maybe that demonstrates that this is really impossible.

So, ok, it fails. But this is where it gets a little weird:

**This app will not die.** I mean force kill does not kill this app. It still shows up in the process list in Xcode. The home button will take you to springboard, and if you relaunch the app, you just get a white screen (I'm guessing because it's not even able to repaint itself?)

When the screen locked while the app was in the foreground, the home button didn't work any more to wake it up. The *power* button didn't work any more. Holding power to shutdown eventually gave a haptic pulse, but did not shutdown the phone. I had to do a reset (power+home) to get it to reboot. I'm amazed that I can lock up the phone this hard from a sandboxed, userland process.

So maybe this isn't the best approach, but it feels just so close to an actual answer that I wanted to share it anyway.